# Finding a range of data between dates formatted as strings

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an older database that has the structure has been linked to and accessed through MS-ACCESS, When this database was created the date was added as short text instead of date format, this brings up problems when trying to query items between two dates.

I cannot edit the format of this table, due to it being linked from an external database through ms-access

The table looks approximately like this.

```
Work_Orders
---
Work_order_num Date_added sysnum Information
10000000       19981212   1      foo
10000001       19991213   2      bar
10000002       19991214   3      Beep
10000003       19991214   3      Boop
10000004       19991215   2      fooo
10000005       19991216   5      barr
10000006       19991216   1      beop
```

I need query all specific work orders within a specific date range. I currently have tried to convert the column into date format using ((CDate(Format([Date_added],"@@@@/@@/@@")). However, I also need to select multiple system numbers from another table, this makes the query too complex and I have yet to find a different method to make this query work.

the system table looks like this:

```
System_Select 
Sysnum Selected
1      True
2      False
3      True
4      False
5      True
```

the query looks like this

```sql
DECLARE
  @START_DATE,
  @END_DATE

SELECT 
  Work_Orders.Work_order_num, 
  (CDate(Format([Date_added],"@@@@\/@@\/@@") AS WO_DATE, 
  Work_Orders.sysnum, 
  Work_Orders.Information

FROM 
  table 
  INNER JOIN System_Select ON 
    Work_Orders.sysnum = System_Select.Sysnum
WHERE
  System_Select.Selected = True
  AND
  ((CDate(Format([Date_added],"@@@@\/@@\/@@")>=START_DATE) 
  AND
  ((CDate(Format([Date_added],"@@@@\/@@\/@@")<=END_DATE)
```

So in short, how will I go about getting a specific range of dates when all the dates are formatted as short strings?

Comment: Can you convert these dates to integers? If so, given the format, the filter you are thinking for dates should work the same for integers too.

Comment: `Where Date_Added between '20190101' and 20190501'`  why do you need to convert.  You can filter on the string dates as is so long as what you're using to filter is in a YYYYMMDD format and string data type..

Comment: The problem is the start date and end date are both inputs with the date format

Comment: Ask yourself is it more work for the system to cast every record's value to a date and lose index use (if they exist) , or convert the inputs to strings for comparison once.  Just food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create simple select queries like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  Work_Orders.Work_order_num, 
  (CDate(Format([Date_added],"@@@@\/@@\/@@") AS TrueDate_added, 
  Work_Orders.sysnum, 
  Work_Orders.Information
FROM Work_Orders
```

to replace your tables. Then, from these, you can build the queries needed filtering on dates the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string into date by splitting into parts and then apply the filter:

```
datefromparts(substring(Date_Added,1,4),substring(Date_Added,5,2),substring(Date_Added,7,2))
```